# prestashop character in the bottom of page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i have a problem with a prestashop website and i have not found any solution in the web.

How you can see in the image, there is a character in the bottom of page, but i have not edit any files. How can i remove it? by css is impossible, if you see the 2nd image, it is not contained in any element.

what could be the problem?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in 'footer.tpl' file.